# Kendo UI chart: e.slice is not a function

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-chart

I'm getting TypeError as "e.slice is not a function" while render the kendo chart. The demo is available in the below. Check console error.

[Kendo chart demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/uTOKi/52)

Appreciate your support to fix the issue.

Comment: because your series objects are getting data directly from the json, you can remove k-data-source="test" from the DIV: http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/iHOqo

Comment: @ezanker Thank you so much for the response. It does the magic :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the binding. I'm passing the data to the series from json and again bind with k-data-source.

[Fixed: Kendo chart demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/iHOqo)

Thanks to @ezanker for figure this out!